# Passing a vector to subset function in lm()?

Tags: r, subset, lm

Consider this example:

```
data <- data.frame(predictor = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), 
dv = c(5,3,5,6,6,1), 
id = c(1,2,3,1,2,3))

model <- lm(dv ~ predictor, subset = id, data = data)
summary(model)
```

I would understand what it would mean to pass, say, `subset = id==1` to the `lm` function--it would use only those observations that has the matching id number. However, when I pass the whole vector, the regression still runs and delivers an output. But what does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

According to `?lm` we see

> subset - an optional vector specifying a subset of observations to be
>   used in the fitting process.

We can see the data used if we run `lmobject$model`:

```
lm(dv ~ predictor, subset = 1, data = data)$model
#  dv predictor
#1  5         1
lm(dv ~ predictor, subset = 1:5, data = data)$model
#  dv predictor
#1  5         1
#2  3         2
#3  5         3
#4  6         4
#5  6         5
data$id
#[1] 1 2 3 1 2 3
lm(dv ~ predictor, subset = id, data = data)$model
#    dv predictor
#1    5         1
#2    3         2
#3    5         3
#1.1  5         1
#2.1  3         2
#3.1  5         3
```

Running id will just repeat rows of the data.

Let me know if anything is still unclear.

Comment: I don't quite understand what "Running id will just repeat rows of the data" means? Does it mean that passing `id` has a meaningful interpretation, or not? What is that interpretation?

Comment: Whether or not anything is meaningful depends on the data. You are only repeating your observations, specifically, rows 1 to 3 of your "data" - twice.

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: Not really. Does"repeat rows of data" mean the dataset is used multiple times?

Comment: Yes it does. Notice the "1.1" "2.1" and "3.1" as the row names. This is quite literally a duplicate of rows 1, 2, and 3.